# operaciones con columnas tipo time en sql

Tags: mysql, sql, time

Tengo dos campos de tipo `time` que son la hora de comienzo de una reunión y la hora de finalización.

Necesito que me devuelva el tiempo de duración en minutos.

Ejemplo:

```
Hora de inicio: 19:00
Hora de fin: 20:30

Duración: 90 (minutos).
```

Gracias !!!

Una vez lograda la solución... ¿Cómo guardo el resultado de la consulta en una variable de php para operar con ella? 
Después del execute no sé como hacer...

```
public function calcular_duracion()
    {
        $consulta = $this->db->prepare("SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute, inicio, fin) from reunion WHERE id = 2");
        $consulta->execute();

       //

        return $tiempo_total;
```

Comment: Que gestor de bases de datos?

Comment: Qué motor de base de datos están usando?, qué versión?, qué tipo de datos es cada columna?

Comment: Que has intentado para que no lo sepas?

Comment: los campos son tipo time. El motor de BBDD es phpMyAdmin o directamente la consola, depende del ordenador.

Comment: He intentado esto : select DATEDIFF(HOUR, inicio, fin) from reunion;

Comment: El motor es MySQL, phpmyadmin es solo una herramienta par conectarte

Comment: Espero honestamente que ninguna reunion empieza un dia y termine otro, porque el tiempo te va a dar... raro...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utiliza la función TIMESTAMPDIFF:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute,horaInicio,hora_fin);
FROM tuTabla;
```

Comment: Me devuelve esto:

Análisis estático:

Se encontraron 1 errores durante el análisis.

Se encontró anteriormente un alias. (near "Minutos" at position 46)
consulta SQL: Documentación

SELECT DATEDIFF (Minute, inicio, fin) % 60 As Minutos FROM reunion LIMIT 0, 25

MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

#1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'

Comment: si quito el alias, tampoco funciona.

Comment: Intenta lo que acabo de editar

Comment: Perfecto!!! me da los minutos!!!

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

Usa `TIMEDIFF` de este modo

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF("12:23", "10:49");
```

Devuelve la diferencia en un formato de tiempo

- La hora de termino va como primer argumento
- La hora de inicio va como segundo término

OPCIÓN RECOMENDADA DE USO

Funciona también en datos de tipo `datetime`

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF("2019:05:23 12:23:00", "2019:05:23 12:14:00");
```

Comment: Sí sí!!! Esta funciona correctamente!!! Muchas Gracias!!!!

Comment: calificada!!! Ahora estoy tratando de hacer que me devuelva minutos. Lo multiplico por 60 pero me devuelve milisegundos...

Comment: Aclara que se deberia usar la segunda version... porque si hay un cambio de dia en el medio, timediff le va a dar cualquier cosa...

Comment: Tienes mucha razón @gbianchi

Comment: Solo paciencia estoy contestando desde mi celular